# What is the difference between Quantum teleportation and Radio waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

[Quantum teleportation over 143 kilometres using active feed- forward](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nature11472.html)

What is the difference between [Quantum teleportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) and [radio waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_waves)?

Comment: What's the similarity?

Comment: Teleportation is in scients mind, since waves was learned pretty hard

Answer (score 7):

Quantum teleportation requires coherent manipulation of photons (or whatever quantum particle is being used for the teleportation; I believe photons in all experiments to date), in order to transport a quantum state from the sender to the receiver.  Coherent manipulation of photons is impossible for radio frequencies with current technology. This means that with current technology, you can send classical information but not quantum information, using radio waves.

To be more specific, what quantum teleportation does is

1. encode an unknown quantum state into photons (or whatever medium you use),
2. transmit the photons,
3. use the photons (and maybe some classical information sent in parallel) to reconstruct the quantum state.

Classical communication cannot be used to transmit quantum states because quantum mechanics (the no-cloning theorem) says that it is impossible to measure an unknown quantum state in enough detail to reconstruct it (you can only get a very bad approximation to it).

Comment: Radio waves consist of photons, just like optical photons, but at much lower frequencies. It certainly is possible that photons at microwave frequencies could be entangled. The challenge is that at low frequencies electromagnetic energy displays more of its wave nature.

Answer (score -1):

simply speaking, and If you mean what is the difference from the usability point of view (information transportation) then they are both can transmit information (classical one)...

But using radio waves, has couple disadvantages (comparing to teleportation) for example in some materials (like air, water...) radio wave speed can be less than the maximum allowed speed: speed of light , plus some materials like metals, can absorb waves and total prevent you from sending information, while quantum teleportation, can avoid those two obstacle (this still theory, till now doing that outside the vacuum is very difficult task)

Also it seems that it will be impossible to interrupt this information (Hakers will be sad) in teleportation alike radio waves, and there is many more applications...